# xcode 7.3 reference icon from assets folder for prototype table view cell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

In Xcode 7 with swift, I'm trying to use icons from my assets folder to display in the icon slot in a normal prototype tableview cell.

My code compiles and the app runs fine, displaying all the proper row text titles in the table, but all the cells use an icon that I (perhaps stupidly) entered into the attributes inspector for the prototype table cell.

By default, the style=Basic table cell does not have an icon to the left of the Title in the storyboard. BUT... if you add the name of an icon image from the assets folder in the image=MyAssetsIconName, the UI builder automatically adds a UIImageView to the left end of the table row cell. And of course all rows display the image that you selected. Which is what my app currently does.

But I would like to change the icon image for each row, so that the image on any row matches the text rows that I display. So I tried to assign a new image (from the assets folder) to each row cell as it was created. I did the assignment right after I assigned the text title to the cell.

Here is my code, which runs fine (but doesn't display the images that I want).

```
class TsbReportsCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Detail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon: UIImageView!
...
}
```

In the table view controller:

```
In the table view controller class:

// define datasources
var reportnames = [String]()
var reportimages = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     reportnames = ["Balance Report",
    "Routine Report",
    "Low Quality Report"]

    reportimages = ["enter.png",
    "exterior.png",
    "export.png"]
}

override func tableView(tableView:.... {
    // all this code works fine
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.Title.text = reportnames[row]

    // here are the lines that seem to have no effect at all
    let rowimage = UIImage(named: reportimages[row])
    cell.Icon = UIImageView(image: rowimage)

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I named an image in the attributes for the table cell row just to get the UI builder to add the imageview placeholder for me. But maybe I'm not allowed to ever override that image, even though I can create an outlet for it.

This seems so simple a problem, but I searched at least 20 posts, the net, the doc, and I still couldn't find anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. You are saying:

```
cell.Icon = UIImageView(image: rowimage)
```

But that does not put this image view *into the interface*! It merely assigns it to the cell's property.

Instead, you need to have an image view *in the cell* and hook an outlet from the cell's `Icon` property to that image view. As a result, `cell.Icon` is the image view *in the interface*. Now you say

```
cell.Icon.image = rowimage
```

Answer (score -1):

Man, are you ever fast at answering questions, Matt. I'm sure I'm not the only one who appreciates that.

It's funny how taking a half hour to write up a decent question for this site makes you start thinking about other things to try. I took a seg fault on one of my tries, and was poking around in the error messages. From them, I got the idea that an ImageView was a structure that had an "image" field in it (or something like that), so I tried some UIImageView x UIImage crosses to see what would happen.

Sure enough, I was trying to assign an ImageView to an Image (I think; I could still be wrong). Here's the code line that worked for me.

```
cell.Icon.image = UIImage(named: reportimages[row])
```

So you can see I'm assigning an image to an image here, which works properly. AND... it must be right, because it's the same code as Matt's!! :-)